# Access Passthrough with Parameter Append into Local table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a passthrough query (qMasterPass), that allows me to then easily call any other SQL Stored Procedure using the below - the example also updates a listbox and this works:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qMasterPass")
     .SQL = "exec DeliverySearch " & txtSearch
     Set Me.lstSearchResults.Recordset = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

How would I modify the above to append to a local Access table (tmpDelPack).  The GeneralSearch SP contains two fields, DeliveryNum and Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is already written into the pass-through query, so you can simply use it as source for an INSERT query.

```
INSERT INTO tmpDelPack
SELECT * FROM qMasterPass
```

and you can run it like this:

```
Set Db = CurrentDb
Db.QueryDefs("qMasterPass").SQL = "exec DeliverySearch " & txtSearch
Db.Execute "INSERT INTO tmpDelPack SELECT * FROM qMasterPass"
```

Comment: Thanks but that pass through is just for reference, I'm actually calling 'DeliverySearch' and just using the definitions from the pass through query to talk to SQL

Comment: Well, that's the point of pass-through queries. See edit. @Michael